# What kind of license does a website in India need to offer song downloads?

Tags: website-features, licenses, music

I have seen many many websites which allow you to download latest songs for free I am doubtful that they have any kind of license or partnership with any music company so if they do not have any such thing how come they are running websites with thousands of pages indexed on Google. If they have any license or partnership for the same what it is? And how they get all the songs on their website from the very first day of release. I am running a website where people can listen songs online but I am using SoundCloud API for that.

I am running a website in India and I want to offer downloadable music to users who visit my website but without violating the law. When I music I am referring to any and every company which provides music so is there anyway I can offer downloads to user.

Comment: Most of these websites are either doing so in violation of the law, or are operating out of a country where copyright law does not apply.

Comment: operating in the sense hosted offshore or available offshore because I see lot of sites in India and AFAIK India comes under almost every copyright stuff

Comment: Sorry but the question is far to broad because copyright laws vary from one country to the next as well as differ from one music company to another. To avoid further disappointment on this website and all the other stack exchange sites I recommend you check out the help center.

Comment: I've edited the question may be this time you guys can suggest something @Mark

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use music licensed under the [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/) licenses.    This music can be freely distributed as long as the various license terms (like attribution).

There are [several music communities](https://creativecommons.org/music-communities) that share and rate this music.  Your site could be another one.